# Why does search on iPhone ask me to send a page to Dropbox?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Searched a few things on the mobile interface and most of my results worked fine. When I searched for 'silver ira' it presents me with a screen that looks as follows:

[image: Bad search results leading to Dropbox on iOS]

Looks like it was sending a bad MIME-type to my phone, so it tried to open it as a file instead of as a webpage.

iOS 4.3.2, iPhone 4

Can anybody else reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't repro:

[image]

Maybe you caught us during a deployment? can *you* repro?

Comment: Perhaps it was a deployment. I could reproduce for a couple hours yesterday, this afternoon I can not. At the time I could, however, it was only that one specific search that would do this. (At least of all the ones I tried.)